# Eclipse error occurrs when running bat files on windows 7?

Tags: eclipse, windows, eclipse-neon

In Eclipse Neon.1 on Windows 7 64 bit I am having an error that occurs every time I run a bat file.  A popup box appears.  I have removed Eclipse Neon.1 and installed both Neon.1 fresh with a fresh workspace.

I believe I am missing some kind of file somewhere on my computer.  But I don't know where and what the file is.

Popup box label:

```
Multiple problems have occurred.
```

Message in box:

```
An error has occurred.  See error log for more details.
```

Error Log - Event Details
Message:

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
```

Exception Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.misc.ProgramImageDescriptor.hashCode(ProgramImageDescriptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaElementImageDescriptor.hashCode(JavaElementImageDescriptor.java:207)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ImageDescriptorRegistry.get(ImageDescriptorRegistry.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaElementImageProvider.getImageLabel(JavaElementImageProvider.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaElementImageProvider.getImageLabel(JavaElementImageProvider.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaUILabelProvider.getImage(JavaUILabelProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerLabelProvider.getImage(PackageExplorerLabelProvider.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorLabelProvider.getImage(JavaNavigatorLabelProvider.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.findImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getColumnImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider$StyledLabelProviderAdapter.getImage(NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.doUpdateItem(CommonViewer.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.ResourceToItemsMapper.updateItem(ResourceToItemsMapper.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.ResourceToItemsMapper.objectChanged(ResourceToItemsMapper.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(CommonViewer.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer$1.labelProviderChanged(ContentViewer.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.BaseLabelProvider$1.run(BaseLabelProvider.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.BaseLabelProvider.fireLabelProviderChanged(BaseLabelProvider.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.lambda$0(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager$1.run(DecoratorManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager.fireListener(DecoratorManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$3.runInUIThread(DecorationScheduler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4203)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3819)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Comment: I am encountering the same issues since I tried to open a *.bat file and checked "use default system editor". After getting rid of the file association it nearly worked everything as before.

Answer (score 0):

The looks like Eclipse bug [502514](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502514).

This is currently scheduled to be fixed in Eclipse 4.6.2.

There is a long discussion in the bug report but it seems to be related to problems with file associations.